# CSV file import errors in to Mysql Workbench 6.3

Tags: csv, import, mysql-workbench

I'm new to Mysql and am using it to make use of several CSV files I have that are very large (some have over a million rows). I'm on Win7-64 Ultimate. I have installed MySql Workbench v. 6.3.6 build 511 64 bit. I read a similar question however I cannot comment since I am new. I am getting a different error anyway.

I have set up a database called crash0715, and created a table called driver_old with five columns. The first column is a report number (set up as INT(20)) that will be keyed to other files. It contains some duplicates depending upon the data in the other columns. The next four columns contain numeric data that is either 1 or 2 digits.

I set up the report_number column as INT(20), primary key, not null.
The other 4 were set up as INT or INT(2)

When I tried to import a little over 1 million rows in a 5-column CSV file (named do.csv in my c:\ root) via the GUI, the program hung. I had let it run over 12 hours and my task manager showed the program was using 25% cpu.

I next tried the command line. After switching to the database, I used 
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'c:/do.csv' INTO TABLE driver_old FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

I had removed the header row from the CSV before trying both imports.

I got the following message:
    QUERY OK, 111 rows affected, 65535 warnings <3.97 sec> Records: 1070145 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 1070034 Warnings: 2273755

I read the first few lines of SHOW WARNINGS and they were as follows:
1264 Out of range value for column 'report_number' for row 1.
1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns

These two repeated for all of the other lines.

There was also a 
1062 Duplicate entry '123456789' for key 'primary' (123456789 is a representative value)

It also reoccurred with the other two codes.

The CSV file has no blanks on the first column, however there are a few in the other ones.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: There are a number of different issues here.  I recommend you divide and conquer.  I would start by taking a smaller subset of the data (perhaps 1000 lines of csv?) and making sure that works first.  The _Out of range..._ and _Duplicate entry..._ messages indicate mismatches between your csv data and the definition of the table you are importing to... you might as well clear that up with a smaller, more convenient data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now successfully imported the 1045767 records. As suggested by another member here, I imported a small 100 row file that gave the same errors. I then opened the csv in Libre Office and saved it. I was able to import it OK.

The problem was the spreadsheet program, GS-Calc. When saving csv files, it gives three options: UTF-8, UTF-16, and ANSI/OEM/ISO. I had initially saved it as UTF-8 and it returned the error.

I saved it as ANSI/OEM/ISO and it was able to be imported OK. I hope this helps others with large csv files in the future.

Answer (score 1):

i solved this by save and export sql insert statement

Answer (score 0):

I would use **bigint** insted of **int**!

Inserting ignore or replace may help with duplicate primary key values!

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/do.csv' **ignore/replace** INTO TABLE driver_old FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

I cannot comment on this question,but it would be great if you could post an url to a picture showing few lines from csv file and code how you created table and inserted data ! That would be very helpful for answering the question!

Comment: I reformatted the file as utf-8 and filled in zeros for all blank cells. Due to the number of rows, I have to use a program called GS-Calc to open, modify, and save the file. I learned I was trying to import the data in the wrong section of the software. When I tried the GUI import after this it gave me another error, so I reformatted as utf-16 and it is now loading. The progress bar is moving, so it is not hung up. I'll post this as the answer if it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The bar finally made it all the way across the screen and I was able to finish the import. The message displayed said \path\do.csv was imported in 80651.335 s (22.4 hours).  Table crash0715.driver_old has been used. 0 records imported. There is no data in the table. I then copied and pasted 100 rows (as suggested above) from my GS-Calc program and saved it as a utf-8 csv file. When I tried to import it, it would not go. I had to open the file in Libre Office (utf-8) and save it there. It imported OK. The issue appears to be the GS-Calc program. I think I have an answer but need to test it.

Answer (score 0):

i change the separator default in mysql by comma

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).